# How to select multiple tables with a query

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a android database(sqlite) within several tables.
now i want to return records with a query;
my query for single table is :

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1;", null);
```

Comment: Do you know SQL at all? ... you can use for example `select * from table1, table2` but i'm pretty sure that it is not what you want(your question is unclear)

Comment: You mean at once? Are do they have anything in common like a foreign key to `Table1` `id` from `Table2` say `table1_id`?

Comment: I think he wants a join

Comment: I know that can use    select * from table1, table 2   but i want to execute  ("SELECT * FROM Table1;SELECT * FROM Table2;SELECT * FROM Table3;")

Comment: Then just do that in different variables?

Comment: so every table has the same columns? it makes no sens ... but even if there is UNION operator

Comment: for example : Cursor[] c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table1;SELECT * FROM Table2;SELECT * FROM Table3;",null)

Comment: So you want the query results in an array? then just run them and add them to the array? This question and your example still not clear what you want out of this

Comment: yes I want to find fill all of array items with db.rawQuery(); in fact with one time of connection to sqlite file return 3 tables.

Comment: What's the motivation behind that?

Comment: my 3 tables have diffrenct columns

Answer (score 2):

If your three tables have the same columns, you could do:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM table3
```

Each of the `SELECT` statements can have a `WHERE` clause.

However, if the above really is what you want, there's a good chance that your database schema can be improved by combining all three tables into one and adding a column to identify where they belong.

Comment: my 3 tables have diffrenct columns

Comment: Then you can ADD the missing columns. i.e.: `..., NULL AS col2, ...` (or a default value like **''** or **0**, depending on the type of the missing column)

Comment: Yes, what @DerGolem said!